# How to convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 using libiconv in C++

Tags: c++, encoding, character-encoding, iconv

I'm using libcurl to fetch some HTML pages.

The HTML pages contain some character references like: `&#1505;&#1500;&#1511;&#1493;&#1501;`

When I read this using libxml2 I'm getting: ׳₪׳¨׳˜׳ ׳¨

is it the ISO-8859-1 encoding?

If so, how do I convert it to UTF-8 to get the correct word.

Thanks

EDIT: I got the solution, MSalters was right, libxml2 does use UTF-8.

I added this to eclipse.ini

-Dfile.encoding=utf-8

and finally I got Hebrew characters on my Eclipse console.
Thanks

Comment: It can't be ISO-8859-1 as that only has characters in the range 0 - 255. 1493 - 1505 aren't in this range (obviously).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions what would it be?
and how do I convert it to UTF-8?

Comment: The numeric character references must come from the document character set which is likely to be unicode. It's nothing to do with the character encoding scheme in use.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is, historically, a character set but it is most commonly used to refer to a character encoding scheme for a subset of unicode.

Comment: I had a quick look.  If this is UTF-16, then they should represent hebrew characters.  Is this the case? (if so, see my answer)

Comment: @stefaanv: UTF-16 is a character encoding form, numeric character references name positions in the document's character set which - if UTF-16 is being used for an encoding form - is going to be unicode (ISO 10646). Decimal 1493 - 1505 are all hebrew characters in unicode whatever character encoding form the document is using.

Comment: @Charles: sorry, my english is not good enough for your remark (or my encoding knowledge).  I was asking about the hebrew characters to be sure that the encoding was UCS-2/UTF-16 instead of ISO-8859-1.  Which it was.  What is your point actually?

Comment: @stefaanv: My point was that it is irrelevant whether the document is encoded using UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1 (in the encoding scheme sense). The numeric references refer to the document character set because that is their point, they are encoding characters in the document character set that cannot be encoded in the encoding scheme in use. You still have to know what the document character set is, but it is unlikely to be anything other than unicode.

Comment: @Charles: okay, that's clearer.  That means that my answer is invalid for this question (especially, since MSalters points out that libxml2 already returns UTF-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the [libxml2 page on i18n](http://xmlsoft.org/encoding.html) ? It explains how libxml2 solves these problems.

You *will* get a `ס` from libxml2. However, you said that you get something like `׳₪׳¨׳˜׳ ׳¨`. Why do you think that you got that? You get an `XMLchar*`. How did you convert that pointer into the string above? Did you perhaps use a debugger? Does that debugger know how to render a `XMLchar*` ? My bet is that the `XMLchar*` is correct, but you used a debugger that cannot render the Unicode in a `XMLchar*`

To answer your last question, a `XMLchar*` is already UTF-8 and needs no further conversion.

Comment: I just printed out the xmlchar* using cout and got ׳₪׳¨׳˜׳ ׳¨
How can I print it right?

Comment: `std::cout` will use the current locale. If that's not a UTF-8 locale (quite likely) then it won't work at all. `std::wcout` usually can print out Unicode, but it expects `wchar_t*` not libxml's `XMLchar*`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Those entities correspond t the decimal value of the Unicode sequence number of your characters. See [this page](http://theorem.ca/~mvcorks/cgi-bin/unicode.pl.cgi?start=0300&end=036F) for example.

You can therefore store your Unicode values as `int`egers and use an algorithm to transform those integers to an UTF-8 multibyte character. See UTF-8 specification for this.

Comment: Not necessary, libxml2 already does that. That's how he got the non-ASCII characters in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer was given in the assumpltion that the encoded text is returned as UTF-16, which as it turns out, isn't the case.**

---

I would guess the encoding is UTF-16 or UCS2.  Specify this as input for iconv.  There might also be an endian issue, have a look [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/07/28/converting-to-utf-16-ucs-2-with-iconv)

---

The c-style way would be (no checking for clarity):

```
iconv_t ic = iconv_open("UCS-2", "UTF-8");
iconv(ic, myUCS2_Text, inputSize, myUTF8-Text, outputSize);
iconv_close(ic);
```

Comment: Those should represent Hebrew characters. 
but right now I'm not getting it.
what would be the correct way to use iconv?

Comment: How should I declare the myUTF8-Text?

This code does not work for me: (the program crashes)
`char ibuf[] = "׳¡׳?׳§׳•׳?";
char obuf[512];
it=iconv_open ("UCS-2", "UTF-8");
iconv(it, (char **)ibuf, &il, (char **)&obuf, &ol)`

Comment: You have initialized il and ol? Pass "&ibuf" instead of "ibuf"